# How to get to blown light bulb

Tags: light-fixture

I am not sure how to actually remove the casing so that I can get to the bulb that has blown?

without breaking something...[image]

Comment: Have you tried gripping the chrome bezel trim and pulling it straight down from the ceiling?

Answer (score 3):

I can't be certain from the image provided but it looks like an LED fixture. A lot of times those LED fixtures are made to not have a replaceable bulb (IE the bulb is built into the fixture itself). If that is the case, then the whole fixture would need to be replaced. If you don't have open access to the ceiling (in the case of an open attic above or the like) it appears you need to pry the metal plate off to access the rest of it. Before doing that maybe try turning the plate to see if it unscrews or detaches from a locking mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you know it in fact to be a screw-in bulb, you are supposed to grip the face of the bulb and rotate it.  You typically grip it with a suction-cup device on a pole.

Dakcenturi thinks it's an LED fixture because you can look right through the diffuser and see a row of yellow things.  Those look all the world like LED emitters and not at all like incandescent filaments.  If so, it might be a screw-in, and might be a sealed fixture.  So heed Dak's advice!

I would favor the LED theory if the outer ring is conformal to the bulb edge (i.e. no gap).  In that case the entire assembly must drop down against a spring.  Sometimes these are retrofit into old incandescent can lights.